# How do I configure my audio?

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio

I have a relatively new build that I can't seem to get audio to work on.

I have one card that i can see with `pacmd list-cards`:

```
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
```

It lists a couple sinks:

```
    sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo/#4: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
```

And can see that my headphones are connected:

```
ports:
    analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:

    analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:

    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
```

My problem is that any program that uses the analog-stereo output (from youtube to RhythmBox) blocks if i have it output audio to `analog-stereo`. I get no sounds and the program won't even run. If i switch the application to use `iec958-stereo` it will run and i can see the volume bars move in `pavucontrol` but since the only port for that output is `S/PDIF` I don't hear anything with my headphones.

**EDIT:**

I turned off pulse as described below. I then used `alsamixer` to turn all the channels up. I can hear white noise through the headphones which gets much quieter if I mute the front and rear mics. However, still no sound from the applications (though they don't block). In case it matters I have a Realtek ALC1150 chip.

**EDIT2:**

Since it really seems like a driver issue and who knows how long that will take to get worked out, I picked up one of [these](https://www.asus.com/us/Sound-Cards/Xonar_DGX/) for ~$35. Dropped it in and it worked first boot.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to check if the problem is with PulseAudio or not, by disabling it temporarily in configs and instead enabling Alsa's mixer thingie.

1. Disable PulseAudio:

   ```
   echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf
   pulseaudio -k
   ```
2. Enable dmix, Alsa's native mixer:

   ```
   sudo gedit ~/.asoundrc
   ```

   to open the .asoundrc config file, and then paste:

   ```
   pcm.!default {
       type plug
       slave.pcm "dmixer"
   }

   pcm.dmixer  {
       type dmix
       ipc_key 1024
       slave {
       pcm "hw:1,0"
       period_time 0
       period_size 1024
       buffer_size 4096
       rate 44100
   }
   bindings {
       0 0
       1 1
   }
   }

   ctl.dmixer {
   type hw
   card 0
   }
   ```

   reboot your computer and see if sound works. If it works, it's a problem with PulseAudio, if it doesn't (even with for example Youtube, or with VLC player when tried with all sound output options), it's most likely a driver or hardware problem. If it works and you can't figure out what was wrong with PA, you may want to keep it like that, I used that setting (slightly modified) for over a year and the only program I tried that has problems with it is Skype.

To reverse the effects simply delete the ~/.pulse/client.conf and ~/.asoundrc files and reboot.